# Testing JDBC Code with JUNIT

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I am using DBUnit and H2 database to test Java code.

In production, we use MySQL. The code which needs to be tested is

```
public int getReplicationLag(String endTime) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    Class.forName(driverClass);
    Properties connProps = new Properties();
    connProps.put("user", userName);
    connProps.put("password", password);
    String query = "select time_to_sec(timediff(ts, ?)) from Foo";
    int currentLag = 0;
    try(Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString, connProps)) {
        try (PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(query)) {
            stmt.setString(1, endTime);
            try(ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()) {
                if (rs.next()) {
                    currentLag = rs.getInt(1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return currentLag;
}
```

I wrote my test case but when I execute the test case it says

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Exception thrown Function "TIME_TO_SEC" 
not found; SQL statement:
select time_to_sec(timediff(ts, ?)) from Foo [90022-190] 
[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@3152cf21
        at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
        at
```

So it seems that the time_to_sec function doesn't exist in the H2 Database.
So now what should I do? start testing against a mysql instance? won't it break some unit testing principles? because testing against a real DB seems like an integration test. (i may be wrong).

What would you do in such case? change the query in a way that is compatible with H2? .. but then I am reinventing the wheel because mysql already gives me that functionality.

Also, if I do bring in mysql then my tests become complex because now I have to encrypt/decrypt credentials. (something which was not a problem with H2).

Comment: Testing against H2 is already an integration test

Comment: humm.... but its more self contained right. So what is the right way... bring Mysql In and do UT against that... will it be a best practice?

Comment: No. Testing against an in-memory database just makes things slightly faster. But it has a huge problem: you're not sure that the code that is tested successfully will work with the actual database, and you're not sure that tests which fail would also fail with the actual database. They make the tests almost useless: they catch basic syntax problems or typos, but cause all sorts of problems, like yours: different reserved words, different types, different functions, different ID generation strategy, etc. etc. Test with the real database.

Comment: Test against a **local instance** of your real database, in your case - MySQL.

Comment: Testing against a local instance of your real DB is nice but I am using a Mac and we use SQL Server...so not really an option.